# Jest unit testing - Async tests failing Timeout

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I got the following error message "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL." On top of that, I also received an error message stating that 0 assertions were executed while expecting 2 assertions.

I've tried extending the timeout to 10 seconds using `jest.setTimeout(10000)`, which should be more than sufficient time to execute that code, but the problem persisted.

I know `m.employeeGetAll()` works because when I test my web app using the browser, I can see the list of employees in the view.

Here's how my test looks like

```
it('Lists all employees successfully', () => {
  expect.assertions(2);
  return m.employeeGetAll().then(result => { //m.employeeGetAll() returns a promise       
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.length).toBe(3);
  });  
});
```

Comment: I've tried adding additional code in the return statement above `.catch(e => {console.log (`Error: ${e}`))`

to try to get some output to see if my promise failed. However, it ends up doing neither and continues to throw the timeout error. I'm confused as to why the promise is never returned. 

The code inside m.employeeGetAll() is simply a call to `mongoose.model().find({}).exec()`

Based on mongoose's documentation, this should return a promise.

Answer (score 3):

The problem I've discovered, was the way async code works.

What cannot be seen in the code snippet was the call to `mongoose.connection.close();` at the very end of my test file.

This call must be done inside `afterEach()` or `afterAll()` function for Jest unit testing framework. Otherwise, the connection to the database will be closed before the tests could complete since all of the calls in my controller methods are asynchronous; This leads to no promise ever being returned and the code goes into timeout.

Since I'm using `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()`, to load data from database once before the start of all tests and to clear the database at the end of all tests, I've included the call to connect to DB using mongoose inside `beforeAll()` as well.

Hope this helps someone who's also stuck in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

with async you have to call `done`

```
it('Lists all employees successfully', (done) => {
  expect.assertions(2);
  return m.employeeGetAll().then(result => { //m.employeeGetAll() returns a promise       
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.length).toBe(3);
    done();
  });  
});
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#promises

I just tried this method and unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error messages.

Comment: @geekster01 You are correct, Jest can return a promise according to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html) but maybe the promise never resolves. If the `done` does not work then you should see why the promise doesn't resolve. Make sure that's the case by setting a breakpoint on console.log

Comment: Thanks for the tip @HMR. I'll check it out.